# o que é tools:context nos arquivos de layouts?

Tags: android

Bom dia pessoal.

Em alguns tutoriais que andei vendo por aí, os criadores definiam essa propriedade, 'tools:context' no gerenciador de layout principal dos xmls.
Procurei no livro do Ricardo Lecheta, mas ele não usa em nenhum momento isso.

Então.. O que é e qual é a finalidade de definir esse 'tools:context?

Exemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente o `tools:context` é usado para dizer qual `Activity` que o Editor de UI deve usar para escolher um tema para renderizar seu layout. E isso tem relação com o `Activity Chooser` na IDE (Android Studio ou Eclipse).

<sub>Resposta baseada nesta [pergunta do Stack Overflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Esse atributo é utilizado para fazer a relação do layout com uma activity.

Por exemplo. Se sua activity usa um tema personalizado você define esse tema no manifesto, se você atribuir o `tools:context` a essa activity, quando você colocar o Layout para editar em modo de visualização gráfica, teoricamente os layouts deverão aplicar o tema definido para essa activity no manifesto.

Mais detalhes sobre o atributo `tools:...` [entrar aqui.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)